# Air Travel within the US

Tags: visas, air-travel, paperwork, minors

I'm 17 years old and I live in Southern CA and I was wondering if I could travel by plane to Washington state even though I don't have a visa. If so, what form of ID would be presentable to TSA? 
(I don't have a driver's license yet)

Comment: What happened to your passport?

Comment: The last passport I had was when I was like 5
I don't have anything recent 
I came here when I was 3 and have been here since

Comment: What is your nationality? Can you renew your passport?

Comment: I was born in Mexico & we went to get it renewed but they said they needed a California ID before getting it renewed, and I haven't gotten one yet. I'm not sure what progress my parents have made since then

Comment: You ought to be able to get your AB 60, then. If you haven't started this, I would do so immediately.

Comment: What is an AB 60? Also, if my parents to manage to fix my US status before I turn 18, what will happen? Do I have to continue on my own?

Comment: The AB 60 is a California driver license issued to non-US citizens who are not in legal immigration status in the US. California began issuing them this year.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know what you mean, just didn't know the proper term.
thank you for your help, really.

Comment: @MichaelHampton http://driveca.org/know-rights-ab-60-license/ says "Do not attempt to use your AB 60 to enter restricted areas of federal facilities, pass through TSA screening"

Comment: @chx but I'll bet the Mexican consulate will accept it as the California ID they want to see before issuing a Mexican passport, which OP *can* use with the TSA.

Comment: @phoog they might but we need to be clear about this, your comment on my answer also mentions the AB 60 and that in itself is not a good document for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anectodally, http://maphappy.org/2015/09/i-basically-used-a-costco-card-to-board-a-flight/ this person have boarded a flight with nothing but a Costco card.

http://sanfrancisco.cbslocal.com/2013/02/07/govt-issued-identification-not-needed-to-pass-through-tsa-security/ says

> A KPIX 5 undercover producer tested this security system, arriving at the San Francisco, San Jose and Oakland airports without official documentation. In every case, the producer was allowed to pass through security using a student ID and personal credit cards and was not subject to a secondary screening before gaining entrance to the terminal.

https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification says

> In the event you arrive at the airport without proper ID, because it is lost or at home, you may still be allowed to fly. TSA officers will request you present two other forms of ID bearing your name. One of the items must bear your name and other identifying information such as photo, address, phone number, social security number or date of birth.
>
> There is no standard list of what alternate forms of ID are acceptable. Examples include: temporary paper driver's licenses, non-driver IDs, social security cards, birth certificates, marriage licenses and credit cards.

Also, if you are a Mexican citizen then you can get a Matricula Consular which is accepted by the TSA.

Comment: The above is only for adults, the person is a minor.

Comment: Yes but the question does not make it clear whether @Lily flies alone or with a companion so I presumed alone.

Comment: yeah, im going alone

Comment: @Lily My wife, a US nonimmigrant alien, has flown without government ID (well, she had her foreign license, but they were rudely dismissive of it when she offered it, even though it is clearly a more secure document than any US license I've ever seen). I did not offer her experiences in answer to your question, though; she is in her late 40s, European, and in the country legally on a quasi-diplomatic visa. As a 17-year-old Mexican without legal immigration status, you have good reason to be wary of this approach. There is a real possibility of being denied boarding. Get the AB60 and passport.

Comment: @Lily rereading my comment I find it a bit unclear.  The possibility of being denied boarding is more about the strength of your secondary ID documents than about your immigration status. You should also consider whether border patrol officers might be checking domestic travelers' status. I believe they do in border airports like McAllen, TX. I have never seen them at LAX, but if you're flying from an airport that is closer to Mexico, you should probably find out whether they are active there.

Answer (score 6):

Travel within the United States requires no visa; as you are flying within the same country.

You will need proof of identification which is [accepted by the TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification); however the site clearly states *"Adult passengers 18 and over..."*; for accompanied minors you don't need identification.

For unaccompanied minors (like yourself), you need to check with the airline. As by law there is no identification required from you, but there needs to be some proof that the person whose name is on the ticket is the person boarding the plane:

> TSA does not require children under 18 to provide identification when
>   traveling with a companion within the United States. Contact the
>   airline for questions regarding specific ID requirements for travelers
>   under 18.

So, its best to check with your airline what is required. They may even fast track your security clearances and give you priority boarding (as an unaccompanied minor).